# code build error while creating code build project 'not authorized to perform: ecr:DescribeRepositories on resource: *'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codebuild

I was given developer access to codebuild in aws but when I try to create a codebuild project the console throws me below error.

```
Error
User: arn:aws:iam::472795581601:user/****** is not authorized to perform: ecr:DescribeRepositories on resource: *
```

full access is restricted for us being developers.
Is there any other access that needs to be granted or something?
thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I think you need to grant power user access : AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser

Comment: thanks for the reply @PubuduJayawardana
but what is power user access? is it something different from admin/ full access?

Comment: Please refer here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html